# When keypad is open screen jumps on Android phones

Tags: cordova, iscroll4

iScroll version being used: 4.1.3

Android Test Device: Sony Ericsson 2.3.4 Android Gingerbread

There are a lot of problems which happen when the keypad is open. Namely

- The screen jumps up and down when the keypad is open
- Input type = password fields lose background
- The screen flickers for dropdowns

Is there a common trend in these bugs? Or should I solve them individually?

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these lines in Android.manifest file

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Comment: still screen jumps occuring,infact this code doesn't solve atleast one problem.Could u suggest any other??